# Retrieving video to stream returns empty in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, html5-video

I'm trying to stream a video file under Laravel `public_path` but it doesn't display the intended file. Here's what I have:

**video.blade.php**

```
<video width="100%" controls>
   <source src="{{ route('playVideo') }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/playVideo', 'User\VideoController@show')->name('playVideo');
```

**VideoController.php**

```
public function show()
{
    
    $pathToFile = public_path('videos/videofile.mp4');

    return response()->file($pathToFile, [
        'Content-Type' => 'video/mp4',
        'Content-Length' => filesize($pathToFile),
    ]);
}
```

This is the result I have but I'm expecting the video here.
[image]

This is the content when I Inspect Element it.

```
<source src="http://localhost:8000/playVideo" type="video/mp4">
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: Seems to me that accessing the video URL directly would be an obvious first troubleshooting step, and allow you to remove all the HTML from the problem. Also your route definition `User\VideoController@show'` is not looking right, unless you're on a very old version of Laravel.

Comment: @miken32 Yes it's working if directly accessing, but I'm doing this to hide the original URL of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh jeez! After days of trying, I'm able let it work this way:

```
    $videoPath = public_path('videos/' . $videoName);

   // this following code disable direct acces to your video when accessing in URL

    $prev_url = url()->previous();

    if(str_contains($prev_url, 'stream/video.mp4') || $prev_url == url('/')){
        return abort(404);
    }

    $stream = new VideoStream($videoPath);
    $response = Response::stream(function () use ($stream) {
        $stream->start();
    }, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'video/mp4',
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        'Expires' => '0',
        'Content-Length' => $stream->getSize(),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline',
        'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff',
    ]);

    $response->send();
```